# reacjs-tinymce Unable to load any skins

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

Using reactjs-tinymce I have defined the following:

```
<Editor
    disabled={true}
    apiKey="MYKEY"
    value={mailBody.msgtext}
    plugins="autoresize"
    init={{
        skin_url: "../../../resources/css/dark",
        skin: "dark",
        menubar: false,
        branding: false,
        statusbar: false,
        toolbar: false,
        content_style: 'body { Roboto, Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size:.85rem; }',
    }}
/>
```

Loading this confiuguration with the skin_url and skin - I get a 404 error:

`https://sp.tinymce.com/i?aid=MYKEY&tna=tinymce_cloud&p=web&dtm=1675439301188&stm=1675439301188&tz=America%2FNew_York&e=se&se_ca=init`

and the text editor will not display.

have confirmed that css and it's required files are loading.

Any help with this would greatlt be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load everything from Tiny Cloud you should not need to use `skin_url` at all.  You need to configure `skin` and `content_css`.  For example:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    skin: "oxide-dark",
    content_css: "dark",
    menubar: false,
    branding: false,
    statusbar: false,
    toolbar: false,
    content_style: 'body { Roboto, Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size:.85rem; }'
});
```

Where `oxide-dark` is the valid name of a skin and `dark` is a valid choice for the content CSS.

Here is a running example:  https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/gyiaab